# How to load style.css after fonts.php in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, overriding, declare

I am developing a website locally in *WordPress* and then uploading it to the temporary dev server to show my progress to the management periodically.

**Problem**:
When I upload everything to the server, I noticed that the styles in my style.css are overridden by the ones in fonts.php. This is my first time using the Wordpress platform. I don't know why, but this is not the case when I am hosting it locally. As you see in the picture, the fonts.php is declared after the style.css. 
Image: [image]

**What I tried**:
I was digging into the wordpress files to find a way to declare fonts.php first and then the style.css later so that style.css will override fonts.php. I found this file in wp-includes/theme.php where I found the style.css being declared but couldnot find for fonts.php. This was a dead-end.

**Does anybody know how to do it?**

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. A friendly tip: When asking questions please paste the relevant code into the the question. Don't use screenshots of your code editor or the html source. It is hard to read and is not searchable.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for letting know, won't do that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Susheel for your post. It is helpful if I have to add a css file externally but didn't solve my problem which was making sure fonts.php is loaded before that.

I FOUND A SIMPLE SOLUTION.
I moved all css that I wanted to override on fonts.php in adaptive.css file which is always loaded after the fonts.php file.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Load the theme stylesheets
function theme_styles()  
{ 

    // Example of loading a jQuery slideshow plugin just on the homepage
    wp_register_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css' );

    // Load all of the styles that need to appear on all pages
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );

    // Conditionally load the FlexSlider CSS on the homepage
    if(is_page('home')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('flexslider');
    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Comment: I had found this as I said in my question. How to make sure that we are declaring fonts.php before it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example to Import Bootstrap CSS Stylesheets in wordpress using wp_enqueue_style()

First thing first you need to insert

```
`<?php wp_head(); ?>`
```

so your theme can use filters and hooks that use the wp_head() hook. So that any theme additions can be easily called.

Make sure you have wp_head(); between the head section of your theme, in the header.php file.

Then create a new file functions.php in the theme directory where index.php also exists. In functions.php we are going to create a new function and then register styles using the wp_register_script function and then we call our styles using the wp_enqueue_style function.

This is the code we are going to use to call in Bootstrap stylesheets.

```
`<?php
function add_stylesheet() {
wp_register_style('bootstrap.min',get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_stylesheet' );
?>`
```

So what does the above code do?

The add_stylesheet() is the name of our created function, you can name it anything you may wish.

Then, we registered our stylesheet through the WordPress function wp_register_style. It accepts 5 different parameters

```
`$handle, $src, $deps, $ver, and $in_footer`
```

After registering our style is done, we can call it using the WordPress function wp_enqueue_style. That is it, this method might seem complicated at first but this is the preferred method of calling in stylesheets in WordPress.